# IMAGEMAGICK: Filling when label contains blanks

Tags: imagemagick

I am using imagemagick to create some simple graphics using the Dymo font.  Here is an example:

```
convert -background White -fill DarkRed -font Dymo -pointsize 72 label:"DYMO FONT" -trim name.png
```

This command creates a file that looks like this:

[image: Dymp font Imagemagick example]

I would like the red to fill all the way across, so that the image looks like a single label. I plan to use this on a page with a black background, which makes it look even worse.

I have played around with this for a while with no luck. Help would be appreciated.

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-12-06

O/S: Fedora 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it does that, but you can generate the text you want by replacing the space with a UTF non-breaking space and sending that to the `stdin` of `convert` and asking `-label` to read its text from the *"file"* called `stdin`:

```
printf "DYMO\xc2\xa0FONT" | 
   convert -background white -fill DarkRed -font DYMO -pointsize 72 label:@- result.png
```

[image]

Add `-trim` just before the output filename if you want the extraneous white space trimmed off from around the edges.

If you had more complicated text and didn't want to do that for all spaces, you could replace spaces using a short piece of `Perl` or `sed` to do it for you...

```
echo -n "Text with lots of spaces." | sed 's/ /\xC2\xA0/g' | convert -background white -fill DarkRed -font dymo -pointsize 72 label:@- -trim label.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark and for the code. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of assistance. Good luck with your project.